# Apache Camel REST post body parameter not shown in OpenAPI / Swagger doc

Tags: swagger, apache-camel, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui, apache-camel-3

I am trying to set up a REST service with Apache Camel (v3.20.0) that, among other routes, offers a POST endpoint that receives a payload in the request body.

I am trying to document my REST interface using the camel-openapi-java package using Java DSL. However, when trying to specify the expected body parameter using `.param().name("body").type(body).description("The post object that is to be published").endParam()` , the parameter is not added to the resulting OpenAPI JSON document.

This is the definition of my REST route:

```
rest().description(serviceConfig.getServiceName(), serviceConfig.getServiceName(), "en")
  .post("/post")
  .description(serviceConfig.getServiceName(), "Receives a post to be published", "en")
  .type(Post.class)
  .param().name("body").type(body).description("The post that is to be published.").endParam()
  .to("direct:servicePipeline");
```

My Rest Configuration is:

```
restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                .host("0.0.0.0")
                .port(8080)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .contextPath(serviceConfig.getVersionPath() + "/" + serviceConfig.getAffordancePath())
                .enableCORS(true)
                .apiContextPath("docs")
                .apiProperty("api.title", serviceConfig.getServiceName())
                .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0")
                .apiProperty("cors", "true");
```

The resulting Open API JSON is generated without the request body parameter and reads as:

```
{"openapi":"3.0.2","info":{"version":"1.0"},"servers":[{"url":"/api/v1/organicposts"}],"paths":{"/post":{"post":{"summary":"Receives a post to be published","operationId":"verb1","responses":{"200":{}}}}},"components":{"schemas":{}}}
```

When I try to declare RestParamType.path and RestParamType.query parameters, it works perfectly fine for those. Any parameter of type `RestParamType.body`, however is ignored.

The class `Post.java` that is expected as payload in the POST request body is implemented as:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Schema(description = "Post Object as expected by the service")
public class Post {

    @Schema(
            name="id",
            description = "ID by which post is stored in local database",
            example="42",
            implementation = Integer.class,
            required = true
    )
    Integer id; // as stored in the posts database

    @Schema(
            name="partnerId",
            description = "ID of partner on behalf of which the post is to be published",
            example="42",
            implementation = Integer.class,
            required = true
    )
    Integer partnerId ; // as stored in partners table

    @Schema(
            name="textContent",
            description = "Text content of the post.",
            example="This is a descriptive comment of the post",
            implementation = String.class,
            required = true
    )
    String textContent ;

    @Schema(
            name="type",
            description = "Type of the post. Determines the expected type of media declared for the post.",
            example="VIDEO",
            implementation = PostType.class,
            required = true
    )
    PostType type;

    @ArraySchema
    @Schema(
            name="media",
            description = "Media objects declared for the post. Single element expected for IMAGE, and VIDEO. More than one element expected for MULTI_IMAGE",
            required = true)
    SpMedia[] media ;
}
```

The pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <camel.version>3.20.0</camel.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rest-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger and OpenAPI dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-openapi-java</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-springdoc-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

What am I missing to have the request body parameter correctly included into the OpenAPI document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply the expected media type(s) for the body payload. You can do that in the Camel REST DSL with the `.consumes()` method. For example:

```java
rest().description(serviceConfig.getServiceName(), serviceConfig.getServiceName(), "en")
  .post("/post")
  .description(serviceConfig.getServiceName(), "Receives a post to be published", "en")
  .type(Post.class)
  .consumes("application/json")
  .param().name("body").type(body).description("The post that is to be published.").endParam()
  .to("direct:servicePipeline");
```

Comment: Thank you James, that indeed solved the problem!